# Does anyone know how to change the Glassfish Icon in the Mac Dock

Tags: macos, glassfish

Whenever we start Glassfish server an icon as shown in the attachment appears in the Dock, has someone ever tried to change that icon. If yes, please can you guide me 'how to do it'

After googling for a while I found a way to hide it but nothing regarding changing it.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Use an icon from another file or folder in OS X

1. Select the file or folder whose icon you want to use, then choose *File* → *Get Info*.
2. At the top of the Info window, click the icon, then choose *Edit* → *Copy*.
3. Select the other file or or folder, then choose *File* → *Get Info*.
4. Click the icon, then choose *Edit* → *Paste*.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to view it in a new tab)</sup>

I also converted this image into the native Mac OS X .icns icon format using the png2icns program which is provided in Ubuntu by the icnsutils package from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not a regular file, folder or an application that i intend to modify. Glassfish server icon is a lil bit different case.

Comment: [Convert Java application to Mac OS X app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037693/convert-java-application-to-mac-os-x-app). [Convert .jar to an OS X executable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695214/convert-jar-to-an-osx-executable) is also an interesting reference, but it is an old question which is now obsolete,